# sudo echo in bash only work with double quote, but not single quote

Tags: bash, echo, sudo

I have 2 variables PASSWORD="123" and FILEPATH="/dir-1/dir2", both are exported as env vars that visible to all users.

I am trying to echo to a file /dir-1/dir2/file that belongs to root as user1.
I knew the issue that because shell redirect won't work with sudo, i.e. `sudo echo <TEXT> >> <FILE>`, so what I did are:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "MY.Password $PASSWORD" >> ${FILEPATH}/file'

sudo bash -c 'echo MY.Password $PASSWORD >> ${FILEPATH}/file'
```

I was expecting to see the last line in the file to be:
`MY.Password 123`
But although the variable got substituted correctly, the expected content of `MY.Password 123` does not appear as the last line in the `/dir-1/dir2/file` file.

I then tried

```
sudo bash -c "echo My.Password '$PASSWORD' >> ${FILEPATH}/file"  

sudo bash -c "echo My.Password $PASSWORD >> ${FILEPATH}/file"
```

Both worked.
Then I start to think if it's because of the single quote, I tried to escape the single quote with double quotes:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "'"MY.Password $PASSWORD"'" >> "'"${FILEPATH}"'"/file'
```

This weird looking command also worked...

Can anyone explain me why my commands don't work, and why the last, weird looking, command worked?

Comment: What exactly didn't work?

Comment: @n.m. Edit the question to say that ```But although the variable got substituted correctly, the expected content of MY.Password 123 does not appear as the last line in the /dir-1/dir2/file file.```

Comment: Single quotes will not expand variables, but, double quotes will do. From `man bash` for `-c` option says as `-c string: If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.  If there are arguments after the string,  they  are  assigned  to the positional parameters, starting with $0.`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: It sounds like you have a misunderstanding about how environment variables work. You say they are "visible to all users", but that's not how env vars work. Each process has its own set of environment variables; they generally get inherited by subprocesses (from the creating process), but `sudo` (by default) clears most of the environment. Thus, setting an environment variable in your shell process (or putting commands in a shell init file that sets them for all of your shell processes) has no effect on the `bash -c` command executed via `sudo`.

Comment: How do you know that the variable got substituted correctly?

Comment: will add a minimum reproducible example today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` doesn't pass your environment by default. `sudo` has an option `-E` or `--preserve-env` that preserves existing environment inside the command run under `sudo`. Examples:

```
# let's set some variable `a`
a=Hello
# will print an empty line
sudo sh -c 'echo $a'
# will print Hello
sudo sh -c "echo $a"
# will print an empty line
sudo -E sh -c 'echo $a'
# because first we need to make `a` exported
export a
# this will print Hello
sudo -E sh -c 'echo $a'
```

When you use double quotes, the expansion happens before calling `sudo`. So expansion/execution goes like this:

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo $a"
+ sudo sh -c 'echo Hello'
+ sh -c 'echo Hello'
+ echo Hello
Hello
```

When you use single quotes the expansion/execution goes like this:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo $a'
+ sh -c 'echo $a'
+ echo $a
# now it depends if `$a` exists here, after `sudo` inside `sh`
+ echo
```

If the variable is not in environment, it will expand to nothing.

> ```
> sudo bash -c 'echo "MY.Password $PASSWORD" >> ${FILEPATH}/file'
> ```

The `PASSWORD` and `FILEPATH` variables are not set inside `sudo`, so they expand to empty strings.

> ```
> sudo bash -c "echo My.Password '$PASSWORD' >> ${FILEPATH}/file"
> ```

First in your shell are the `PASSWORD` and `FILEPATH` variables expanded. Then `sudo` is executed, then `bash` is executed. Inside `bash` the `echo My.Password 'PASSWORD' >> FILEPATH/file` is executed so it works.

> ```
> sudo bash -c 'echo "'"MY.Password $PASSWORD"'" >> "'"${FILEPATH}"'"/file'
> ```

Let's split it with newlines:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "'\
"MY.Password $PASSWORD"\
'" >> "'\
"${FILEPATH}"\
'"/file'
```

Because your variables are inside `"` they are expanded before calling sudo. Then inside `sudo` they are already expanded and the values are properly quoted, the values are inside `"` in the child shell. This is the "most" correct form, because expanded values should be properly quoted, inside `"`, so that nothing strange happens when ex. `FILEPATH` has a space in it.

I usually do this:

```
 sudo bash -c 'echo MY.Password "$1" >> "$2"/file' -- "$PASSWORD" "$FILEPATH"
```

It makes me not worry about using `"` quotes inside the shell and nonetheless pass properly quoted variables to the shell without changing the environment.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
 export PASSWORD FILEPATH
 sudo -E bash -c 'echo MY.Password "$PASSWORD" >> "$FILEPATH"/file'
```

Or go for a tea:

```
echo  MY.Password "$PASSWORD" | sudo tee -a "$FILEPATH"/file
```